# WCF TCP Channel Access

Tags: wcf

I have a Windows service that opens a WCF TCP port for communication. It was working fine up till about 3 weeks ago - and after an update (service is running on Windows Server 2016) the TCP channel stated failing - with closed port message when trying to access functionality on the TCP channel. Does anyone know what would have caused this.

Peter

Comment: any specific error log in Event Viewer or some other log ?

Comment: this is the error I'm getting calling an operation on the WCF proxy --

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9959974

HResult -2146233087 

InnerException 
  "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
   ErrorCode 10054 
   HResult -2147467259

Comment: Try to disable firewall. Server side as well as client side.

Comment: How about the chances of  same port being used by another application?

Comment: firewall is off -- the communication is happening on the same server

Comment: brand new server - not much on -- checked all ports -- no conflicts
- I also changed the ports - and still did not work

Comment: again -- the operation was working fine one day - then the next day stopped -- the only thing I an think of happening was an update

Comment: I have been ale to get it working again . I have no clue what made it worked -- just recompiling and redeployning in general. This question can be closed.